# If + Boolean em Java

Tags: java

Boa noite, estou com dificuldade no meu código. Estou usando 2 classes para desenvolver um programa que contabiliza vitória de um time (estilo Placar de Futebol).
O meu problema é na hora dos "if" e "else". Quando eu coloco o `if` e o `else`, tanto dentro de `CasaDoCorinthians` quanto desse método que eu declarei em baixo, ele aparece errado no meu método principal (quando chamo dentro do objeto os atributos);
Não sei se é porque esta if (`CasaDoCorinthians == true`), mas quando coloco só um `=` de atribuição o código não chama o `else` e pula o outro `if` da parte de baixo do código - dentro do método `void`.

O que está errado no código?

```
package futebol;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Futebol {

    String corinthians, flamengo;
    boolean CasaDoCorinthians;
    private int golsFeitosFlamengo, golsFeitosCorinthians;
    protected int resultado;

    public Futebol() { 
        golsFeitosFlamengo = 0;
        resultado = 0;
        golsFeitosCorinthians = 0;

        corinthians = "camisa principal";
        flamengo = "camisa principal";
    }

    public String getCorinthians() {
        return corinthians;
    }

    public void setCorinthians(String newCorinthians) {
        if (CasaDoCorinthians == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O Corinthians está jogando em casa!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O Flamengo está jogando em casa!");
        }
    }

    public int getGolsFeitosFlamengo() {
        return golsFeitosFlamengo;
    }

    public void setGolsFeitosFlamengo(int golsFeitosFlamengo) {
        this.golsFeitosFlamengo = golsFeitosFlamengo;
    }

    public int getGolsFeitosCorinthians() {
        return golsFeitosCorinthians;
    }

    public void setGolsFeitosCorinthians(int golsFeitosCorinthians) {
        this.golsFeitosCorinthians = golsFeitosCorinthians;
    }

    void comecoJogo() {
        if (CasaDoCorinthians == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O Jogo é na Arena Itaquera");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O Jogo é no Maracanã");
        }
    }

    void resultado() {
        resultado = golsFeitosCorinthians - golsFeitosFlamengo;

        if (resultado > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vitória do Corinthians");
        }
        if (resultado < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vitória do Flamengo");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jogo Empatado");
        } 
    }
}
```

Classe 2:

```
package futebol;

public class Partida {

    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        Futebol jogo = new Futebol();
        jogo.comecoJogo();
        jogo.CasaDoCorinthians = (true);
        jogo.setGolsFeitosFlamengo(5);
        jogo.setGolsFeitosCorinthians(4);

        jogo.resultado();
    }
}
```

Comment: Em qual método você esta tendo problema?
Tente formular sua pergunta melhor, isso ajudar a quem vai responder a dar um resposta mais precisa e a quem tem a mesma duvida a encontrar sua pergunta.

Comment: André, como a pergunta foi fechada eu não posso elaborar uma resposta. Porém, um primeiro problema é que você está chamando `jogo.comecoJogo();`antes de `jogo.CasaDoCorinthians = true; logo o código está imprimindo que o jogo é Maracanã. Outro problema é que o método `setCorinthians`: 1. Não faz sentido e 2. Não está sendo chamado. O que você provavelmente quer é um método `setCasaDoCorinthians(boolean casaDoCorinthians)` que atribui o `boolean` e potencialmente imprime as mensagens que no momento estão em `setCorinthians`.

Comment: Finalmente, seu código tem algumas variáveis não utilizadas (e.g., `String corinthians, flamengo;`), outras que poderiam ser privadas (`casaDoCorinthians`, `resultado`), etc. De resto, muita coisa pode ser simplificada e generalizada (e.g., funcionar com dois times genéricos ao invés de apenas corinthians e flamengo). Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Anthony Accioly a pergunda dele não foi fechada, e sim marcada como pendente.

Comment: É bem altruísta procurar se esforçar para encontrar o problema por conta própria e fornecer uma solução. Mas isso o desencorajará a melhorar a perguntar. E é importante que não só as resposta sejam bem elaboradas mas as perguntas também para que possam ajudar pessoas com o mesmo problema ou duvida.